# libFLAC++ with c++Builder error

Tags: c++builder

libflac++ includer to project
but there is error.. what's wrong?

```
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'FLAC::Encoder::File::~File()' referenced from C:\USERS\INK\DESKTOP\AMUU UI\RELEASE\UNIT1.OBJ
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'FLAC::Encoder::Stream::~Stream()' referenced from C:\USERS\INK\DESKTOP\AMUU UI\RELEASE\UNIT1.OBJ
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'FLAC::Encoder::File::File()' referenced from C:\USERS\INK\DESKTOP\AMUU UI\RELEASE\UNIT1.OBJ
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'FLAC::Encoder::Stream::is_valid() const' referenced from C:\USERS\INK\DESKTOP\AMUU UI\RELEASE\UNIT1.OBJ
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'FLAC::Encoder::Stream::set_ogg_serial_number(long)' referenced from C:\USERS\INK\DESKTOP\AMUU UI\RELEASE\UNIT1.OBJ
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'FLAC::Encoder::Stream::set_verify(bool)' referenced from C:\USERS\INK\DESKTOP\AMUU UI\RELEASE\UNIT1.OBJ
[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'FLAC::Encoder::Stream::set_streamable_subset(bool)' referenced from C:\USERS\INK\DESKTOP\AMUU UI\RELEASE\UNIT1.OBJ
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you either compile the libFLAC source into the project or link with the library.